# Why am I false?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Getting this error around 9:30AM (CST):

[image]

when visiting the Questions/newest tab.

Comment: For me it's because I am married. Don't know about other people. Oh, False. I read it as "wrong."

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/lol-debugging-are-we-so-homepage-alerts-false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a problem with some javascript code. The devs have pushed out a fix.